# Is the memory management of an activity changed by binding to a local service?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

Is the memory management of an activity changed by binding to a local service?  In other words, if an activity binds to a local service, does the system try to keep the activity alive?  Or is there no effect on the activity itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity should unbind from the service if it is stopped (is not shown). When the activity is active Android will not remove it unless its runs out of memory.

But the service profits from the bound activity: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

"The Android system will force-stop a service only when memory is low and it must recover system resources for the activity that has user focus. If the service is bound to an activity that has user focus, then it's less likely to be killed, and if the service is declared to run in the foreground (discussed later), then it will almost never be killed."

Comment: I know that the service will not be destroyed if an activity is bound to it, but is there any affect on the activity itself.  Will the activity not be destroyed if it is bound to the service (Even if the activity is stopped

Comment: According to the documentation there should be no effect since the likeliness of the activity being destroyed only depends on its life cycle status.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I guess, my question is a mute point if my activity should unbind from the service when the activity is stopped.